# Where to put "server side" code in a asp.net project that should execute periodically?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple page which interacts with a db, so far so good. I'd like to periodically truncate a table in the db, but am not sure where to put the logic.

I have tried using a thread in the page's code-behind, but this doesn't seem to make too much sense since the logic doesn't have anything to do with the page. Also, I don't know how to stop the thread since the its lifetime isn't linked to anything on the page.

I have also tried to use PageAsyncTask, but once again this is specific to the page.

Comment: Sounds more like a job for a job/task scheduler than something your website needs to be doing.

Comment: @nbokmans agreed, for simplicity's sake I was hoping for a solution within the asp.net project - however I'm only just dipping into asp.net and if what I'm trying to do isn't appropriate... at least I've learnt something.

Comment: This article by SCOTT HANSELMAN would help you to understand and implement this, https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx Although if your task has no relation with website then you can develop a desktop application like widows service.

Comment: Thanks @Adil that's great - if you add as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [article](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) by SCOTT HANSELMAN would help you to understand and implement the periodic task that should be repeated after a set interval of time.

Although if your task has no relation with website then you can develop a desktop application like widows service.